# How to compute gradient of the error with respect to the model input?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Given a simple 2 layer neural network, the traditional idea is to compute the gradient w.r.t. the weights/model parameters. For an experiment, I want to compute the gradient of the error w.r.t the input. Are there existing Pytorch methods that can allow me to do this?

More concretely, consider the following neural network:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_features, n_hidden, n_classes, dropout):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(n_features, n_hidden)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_classes)
        self.dropout = dropout

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, self.dropout, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

I instantiate the model and an optimizer for the weights as follows:

```
import torch.optim as optim
model = NeuralNet(n_features=args.n_features,
            n_hidden=args.n_hidden,
            n_classes=args.n_classes,
            dropout=args.dropout)
optimizer_w = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

While training, I update the weights as usual. Now, given that I have values for the weights, I should be able to use them to compute the gradient w.r.t. the input. I am unable to figure out how.

```
def train(epoch):
    t = time.time()
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(features)
    loss_train = F.nll_loss(output[idx_train], labels[idx_train])
    acc_train = accuracy(output[idx_train], labels[idx_train])
    loss_train.backward()
    optimizer_w.step()

    # grad_features = loss_train.backward() w.r.t to features
    # features -= 0.001 * grad_features

for epoch in range(args.epochs):
    train(epoch)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, just set `input.requires_grad = True` for each input batch you're feeding in, and then after `loss.backward()` you should see that `input.grad` holds the expected gradient. In other words, if your input to the model (which you call `features` in your code) is some `M x N x ...` tensor, `features.grad` will be a tensor of the same shape, where each element of `grad` holds the gradient with respect to the corresponding element of `features`. In my comments below, I use `i` as a generalized index - if your `parameters` has for instance 3 dimensions, replace it with `features.grad[i, j, k]`, etc.

Regarding the error you're getting: PyTorch operations build a tree representing the mathematical operation they are describing, which is then used for differentiation. For instance `c = a + b` will create a tree where `a` and `b` are leaf nodes and `c` is not a leaf (since it results from other expressions). Your model is the expression, and its inputs as well as parameters are the leaves, whereas all intermediate and final outputs are not leaves. You can think of leaves as "constants" or "parameters" and of all other variables as of functions of those. This message tells you that you can only set `requires_grad` of leaf variables.

Your problem is that at the first iteration, `features` is random (or however else you initialize) and is therefore a valid leaf. After your first iteration, `features` is no longer a leaf, since it becomes an expression calculated based on the previous ones. In pseudocode, you have

```
f_1 = initial_value # valid leaf
f_2 = f_1 + your_grad_stuff # not a leaf: f_2 is a function of f_1
```

to deal with that you need to use [`detach`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.detach), which breaks the links in the tree, and makes the autograd treat a tensor as if it was constant, no matter how it was created. In particular, no gradient calculations will be backpropagated through `detach`. So you need something like

```
features = features.detach() - 0.01 * features.grad
```

Note: perhaps you need to sprinkle a couple more `detach`es here and there, which is hard to say without seeing your whole code and knowing the exact purpose.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean I should add a line `features.require_grad = True` inside the `train` method? And that the i-th row of the `features.grad` tensor will contain the value of the gradient w.r.t. the current model parameters for the i-th feature/input?

Comment: Yes, it goes in `train`. `features.grad[i]` will contain the derivative of `loss_train` with respect to `features[i]`, which is what you are asking for in the title of your question.

Comment: A small follow-up question: `features.grad[i]` returns the gradient of `loss_train` for the i-th input (`features[i]`) and thus `features[i][j]` is the gradient for the j-th feature for the i-th input. Is this interpretation correct? Also, inside `train`, I am trying to "update" the features by doing the following: `features[:, j] -= 0.01 * features.grad[:, j]` for some j. But I get this error - `RuntimeError: you can only change requires_grad flags of leaf variables.`. What does this mean and what's the right way to update the features?

Comment: This is a very helpful explanation. Thank you. 
`detach()` did not work and gave the same error as before, however, [`detach_()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.detach_) did since the latter detaches from the current graph and makes it a leaf which the former does not. Also, `detach_()` does not allow in-place operations, it needed to be called separately. Does it matter whether I detach the tensor before or after the updates from the gradient stuff? 
I'm accepting your answer. Perhaps you may want to consider editing to `detach_()`.